# Grouping by a property and make list under each property from sql to C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my website, I want to show projects with its associated technologies and their technologiesId for each project. so I am using a stored procedure and I have three tables -

Projects 
Technologies
ProjectTechnologies (Relational table for Project and Technologies)

I am using procedure dbo. GetData and use this query in the procedure-

```
SELECT pt.ProjectId, p.ProjectTitle, p.ShortContent, p.ThumbImage,t.TechnologyName, pt.TechnologyId FROM dbo.ProjectTechnologies as pt
INNER JOIN dbo.Projects p
    ON pt.ProjectId =p.ProjectId
INNER JOIN dbo.Technologies t
    ON pt.TechnologyId = t.TechnologyId
```

So It will Return Project table Columns many times because of each project have many technologies, but now the problem is on the c# code I am using View model to get data -

```
 public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

    public string ShortContent { get; set; }


    public string ProjectImage { get; set; }
    public string ThumbImage { get; set; }

    public List<string> TechnologyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> TechnologyId { get; set; }
}
```

So now, I want to get List of Projects further List of technology name and technology Id. How to manipulate data after getting from SQL in this model form. If I will use for loop then it will very long code and also need to check many conditions so is there any way to map the model with data easily?

Comment: Can you give an output example? How you want the technologies to be listed? In a comma separated values or in different rows

Comment: In ouput I want to simply applying loop on ProjectViewModel so I can get all projects and then inside this loop again a loop to get each project technology name and Id with diffrent row @Zaki Mohammed

Comment: Means I want to make a list of Projects and further list of technologies for each projects same as shown in model above